# WCF Service stops working after 100 calls

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, connection

I am facing an issue when working with my WCF service. I consumed my WCF service in a console application and it works fine till 100 requests (in a loop). But it stops working after 100 requests. I have already used

```
<serviceThrottling
                    maxConcurrentCalls="500"
                    maxConcurrentInstances="500"
                    maxConcurrentSessions="500"/>
```

in my config but it has not effect on this issue. I have closed the connection after every call to the service but still the issue persists.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Below is my web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>


  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="PriceGain" connectionString="Server=xyz.abc.com;Database=SomeDB;User Id=appuser;password=xxxxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="AirGainUtilities.Service.Utilities" behaviorConfiguration="UtilitiesBehavior">
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
         <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.1/AirGain.Utilities.Service/Utilities.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AirGainUtilities.Service.IUtilities" /> 
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="UtilitiesBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

          <serviceThrottling
                    maxConcurrentCalls="5000"
                    maxConcurrentInstances="5000"
                    maxConcurrentSessions="5000"/>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
       <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" /> 
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="Utilities.svc" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you enable FaultExceptions?

Comment: Hi Shuto,
As a matter of fact, I am not getting any exception either
I am new to WCF, may be I am doing something Wrong:

 public List<string> GetDestinationHotelId(string DestinationAirport)
        {
            try
            {
                Package objPkg = new Package();
                return objPkg.GetDestinationHotelId(DestinationAirport);
            }
            catch (Exception fe)
            {
                throw new FaultException(fe.Message);
            }
            //return null;
        }

Above is my Service contract method.

Comment: Below is my client application code to consume it:
int x = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    x++;
                    using (AirGainUtilities.Service.UtilitiesClient UC = new AirGainUtilities.Service.UtilitiesClient())
                    {

                        List<string> lstHotels = UC.GetDestinationHotelId("SJD");

                        if (lstHotels.Count <= 0)
                        {
                            x++;
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: Please edit your question and add clients code there

Comment: Oops,
I found the Problem... It had nothing to do with the WCF.
There was a problem in the class Package code which was not throwing any error.
Sorry & thanks daniell89 , Shuto Mbofana,

Comment: No worries mate. Glad you managed to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was an **open DB connection** in the GetDestinationHotelId method in the Package Class. The DB connections were not closed due to an exception and after 100 open connections **MAX CONNECTION POOL LIMIT** was reached.

Really silly at my end :-(